# Changing one menu item position in Joomla 3 with CSS

Tags: css, joomla3.2

A question is bothering me.

I trying to modify a menu item in my menu. It's the last item in it.

How could I change its position with CSS?

Dev Tools say that item has item-124 class in html.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should perhaps reorder your menu items inside your Joomla menu manager - to reorder using css only would cause you headaches at a later stage :)

Do you want to edit where it it positioned on the page or just the order in which it displays?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I would like to change page position of the menu item. I know I have do style the item in CSS and then use CSS link type in Joomla manager, but the problem is the right declaration of the style for this item to be called upon from Joomla.

Comment: Go and grab yourself Firebug for Firefox its amazingly helpful - install it and hit f12 then hover over your menu item - you will be able to get the full css path of any element on the page, its a very helpful extension for editing Joomla css.

Comment: it would be something like this depending on your html setup

div#topmenu div#hornav div.moduletable ul.menu li.item-124 {}

Comment: no probs mate - firebug really helps alot to learn about Joomla css classes output.

Comment: I am using the Inspect element in Firefox. I like it better. For local dev is quite good for CSS.